# Как изменить размер изображения перезаписав файл

Tags: c#

Есть метод для изменения размера картинки. Как сделать чтобы он перезаписывал файл. В данный момент он выдаёт ошибку

```
{"В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида."}

  public void ResizeImage(string fileName, int width, int height)
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName))
            {
                new Bitmap(image, width, height).Save(fileName);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Из документации метода [Save(string filename)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_):

> Exceptions:
> **ExternalException**
>
> The image was saved with the wrong image
> format.
>
> -or-
>
> The image **was saved to the same file** it was created from.

Иными словами, метод не позволяет записывать `Bitmap` в тот же файл, из которого он был создан. Попробуйте сначала записать `Bitmap` в новый файл, затем удалить старый и переименовать новый файл.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего поступить так:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image, width, height);
image.Dispose();
bitmap.Save(fileName);
bitmap.Dispose();
```

Сперва диспозим оригинальное изображение (освобождаем ресурс - хендл, связанный с ним). После чего становится возможным сохранять в тот же файл.

В конце освобождаем ресурсы, занятые новым изображением с изменённым размером.

Можно применить `using`, но только для второго изображения. Потому что момент освобождения первого мы должны контролировать сами.

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image, width, height))
{
    image.Dispose();
    bitmap.Save(fileName);
}
```